# Name a folder when zipping a file in node

Tags: node.js, zip, jszip

I am creating a zip file with JSZip but I have a very specific requirement that I can't figure out how to do.

When this file is unzipped it needs to create a folder with two files inside it. Let's say foo.zip unzips to create a folder foo with files bar.mp4 and baz.png.

So far that's easy enough I can just go

```
let zip = new Zip()
let folder = zip.folder('foo')
folder.file(`bar.mp4`, videoData)
folder.file(`baz.png`, imageData)
// Save as foo.zip
```

But what I need to happen is if I rename foo.zip to horse.zip then the folder created should be called horse. If I use the above code then it will always be called foo. I know this is possible because I have several zip files that currently do this.

Edit: I'm not tied to JSZip here either. I'm happy to do this any way that's possible. Code will only be run on the server.

Comment: If the unzip is done outside your app, you're probably looking for [self-extracting archives](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/179). However, I don't know how to build one in nodejs.

Comment: That would only create a windows executable though. Android/IOS/Unix based OS's can't open it.